# Jenkins Blue Ocean won't show Agent when creating a Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm new to Blue Ocean, and I'm following [their tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/create-a-pipeline-in-blue-ocean/#create-your-pipeline-project-in-blue-ocean) which tells me to run:

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -u root \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v "$HOME":/home \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

It fired up the docker instance, I got to the Blue Ocean screen, Clicked on create a new pipeline, set the GitHub token, Etc.

Now I'm at the part where you [select the Agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/create-a-pipeline-in-blue-ocean/#create-your-initial-pipeline), but mine has no agent:

[image]

Moreover, if I click the save button and then "save & run" it gets stuck and the docker container output throws:

```
WARNING: Error while serving http://localhost:8080/blue/rest/pipeline-metadata/agentMetadata
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  ... <stack trace here> ...

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.DeclarativeAgentDescriptor.all()Lhudson/ExtensionList;
```

I'm blank now and don't know what to do since that was the "out of the box" tutorial.

How can I fix this so I can advance?

Comment: Maybe this is a new issue, since I don't see much in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47788?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20blueocean-plugin%20AND%20text%20~%20%22agent%20select%22

Comment: @VonC guess I'll open a bug

Comment: Looks like it was fixed. The latest image does not have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a indeed a bug. I reported it and it is now solved. Here's the JIRA ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50805